# How to connect to a "central" MySQL database with Java so we can INSERT and SELECT without having the root and password in the source code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, webserver

I have a central SQL server which can be INSERTED INTO and SELECTED from via PHP. However I have built a Java application which I hope to be able to Insert and select stuff in the SQL table with that I have hosted on a web server.

How would I go about doing this? I don't really want to have the root password with JDBC in the source code as even if it is obfuscating it can easily be deobfuscated and then the user has direct access to the database.

Someone said to me that I should use an API but I don't see how I will be able to interact with the database by doing this.

Comment: You can create a new user with certain permissions to use with Java. You don't need api. Ofcourse, you can write api with php so your and other (possible) applications can interact with it to manupulate database. They're different approaches.

Comment: Externalize the configuration. Mount it into your deployment through your CD pipeline. For example, if you deploy to Kubernetes/OpenShift, use [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Comment: How is your PHP connecting to the DB? Where is the password stored for that? Why do you not have the same concern there?

Comment: @PatrickQ In Java I would have to write the root and password in the source code, which can be viewed when the app is decompiled. However PHP is back end on a server so can not be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a PHP application running server side that handles database interaction; I recommend letting that handle if for you.

Write an API in PHP that handles all of the database interactions and send requests to that API from your java application. (I'd probably have the users create an authorization token to pass along to the API as well so you can track who is using your API and limit access).

Your application can then send HTTP(s) POST/GET/etc requests to your PHP that will then handle the database interactions and return the results. Your database username and password will be kept on your server and your application will not need to know them.

If you don't want to rely on a backend service and want your client application to interact directly with the database... You'll probably have to include a username and password in the code. BUT I'd create a separate user in the database with limited accessibility that could be removed anytime you suspect abuse.

Comment: Please don't even suggest that they try connecting to the DB directly from the front end (how they now would be able to do that). That would be a _massive_ security issue, different user or not, since _any_ user would be able to insert what ever data they want or update the current data, completely messing up the database.